# How to create a n-dims array with unknown n and unknown length of dims in C++?

Tags: c++

I have an array, `int dims[n]`, where `n` means dims, for example n`=3` means there are 3 dims.

`dims[i]` stores the corresponding length of the dim.

I want to create an array, `arr[dims[0]][dims[1]][...][dims[n]]`, is there any good methods?

(`dims[n]` is not sure when the code is compiled, I am not able to define a certain format of `arr`)

I need the array for a function with argument `double*`, the function will read an n-dimensional array from file and could not put data into a 1-dimensional array (in this case, it will report an memory error and I am not able to reconfigure the function).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thats not the question at all, OP wants an N dimensional array where N is only known at run time

Comment: create a single array length dim[0] * dim[1] * dim[2] ... * dim[n]. then calculate the offsets yourself

Comment: Whenever you think "dynamic array" your next though should almost always be `std::vector`.

Comment: You can not allocate an array with unknown number of dimensions, can't even give it a type. So as pm100 suggests you have to make a 1 dimesional array and compute indexes yourself. I recommend putting that in a class that takes `std::vector<size_t> dims` in the constructor and provides an `operator[](const std::vector<size_t>)` for access to elements. You can add support for ranges, views, spans, slizes as well.

Comment: When I use python, numpy package, I could use a = np.zeros((1, 2, 3)) to create an array with shape (1, 2, 3). I mean, how should I do this in C++?

Comment: The shape is  of course a certain number, dims will be generated in the previous code. Then I will need to storage some data with such an array.

Comment: "how should I do this in C++" You implement a class that does this, or find a third-party library that has already implemented one for you. No such class exists in the C++ standard library, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: The closest thing to numpy like matrices and tensors in c++ would be a library called Eigen which has dynamically sized objects I believe (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/). If that doesn't work for you, the simplest thing would be to use a flat std:vector with some index calculation routines packaged into a class.

Comment: Use `std::valarray` and related functions. With that you can easily do it.